# DIV height 100% for remaining space under another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a header bar for a page I made with a height of `150px`. Under that area I want another DIV to fill the remaining space (width and height) all across the screen and to the bottom of the screen. I've tried setting `height: 100%` for the DIV, but that causes the screen to become scrollable and I only want it to fill the remainder of the page. NOTE: There is NO footer or anything under it.

Using jQuery/Javascript is acceptable, but CSS-only is prefered (if possible). If using jQuery, please explain the proper way to have it implemented into the page (I'm assuming `$(function() {...});` under the `<style>` tag in the head.

I've tried searching for a result before, but nothing seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I basically made 3 options for you. click on the 'like this' in the below paragraph to see what they all look like without any text.  Click on the A). B). and C). links in the paragraphs below that to see the difference between the three options. Check how each one scrolls differently, they are all different I promise. After you look at all three you can read how the one you want is implemented. (that is if you like any of them.) Hope you like it, no problem if you don't :)

I'll have a go at this, because it honestly depends on what you're going after there are multiple ways to look at it and it depends on your end goal.  I will cover three possible scenarios: (which all look the same without text mind you, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/74HTg/1/show), but if you want to see what they look like with text click the letters. Make sure you scroll the page to see the difference between them.)

(Just as a side note I based A). and B). off how [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) does it.)

**[A).](http://jsfiddle.net/74HTg/2/show)** You just want it to look like one div on top of the other (header div on top of main-content div) and display like that, but you still want the page to scroll if the 2nd div's text overflows. In this implementation when they scroll will move the header out of view, but if you don't want the header div to move out of view that leads me to

**[B).](http://jsfiddle.net/4GRkX/2/show)** Same as the first header div on top of main-content div, but when they scroll the header div will still stay in place at the top instead of moving out of view.

and last of all,
**[C).](http://jsfiddle.net/PUNU2/2/show)** You really do want the div to stretch to the bottom of the screen and never have the scroll bar for the whole page.  This could be used in some cases, for instance, Spotify makes a nice music app with this kind of style so that you never scroll the whole page just panes in the page.

Ok so first here is the html code used to construct all three of them

```
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main-content"></div>
</body>
```

And now to the fun part...

I will provide a Fiddle for the following examples, and with the css I will put the necessary code at the top and the unneccessary code at the bottom. (The html may have some unneccasary text so just ignore that.  I just want you to see the page scrolls differently on the three.)

### A).

no need to rephrase what it is so I'll just show you the code that is necessary.

First, [here is A). without the text](http://jsfiddle.net/74HTg/1/) just so you can see what it looks like the others until the content gets too large.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74HTg/2/) with the text so you can see how it differs.

Here is the necessary css for A). (the background-color isn't completely necessary, but it is somewhat necessary to show the point.)

```
body {
    padding-top: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #676767;
}
```

and now for...

### B).

First, [here is B). without the text](http://jsfiddle.net/4GRkX/1/) just so you can see what it looks like the others until the content gets too large.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GRkX/2/) with the text so you can see how it differs.

Here is the necessary css for B).

```
body {
    padding-top: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #676767;
}
```

As you can probably tell the only difference is the `position: fixed` on the .header, but look at the two examples to see the difference it makes.

and now last of all C).,

### C).

First, [here is C). without the text](http://jsfiddle.net/PUNU2/1/) just so you can see what it looks like the others until the content gets too large.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUNU2/2/) with the text so you can see how it differs, and with I'll call option 1 where it has a scroll bar just for that area's overflowing content.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUNU2/3/) with the text so you can see how it differs, and with I'll call option 2 where it hides the overflowing content. (This is honestly bad practice and I wouldn't do it. So if I may suggest. I would go with option 1 of C).)

Here is the necessary css for C).

```
body {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #676767;
}

.main-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I won't explain it, but here is [an article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) on positioning that will.

here is the only necessary css for option 1 is adding `overflow-y: auto` to `.main-content`, but if you want to go with option 2 which I don't suggest you can go with `overflow-y: hidden` on `.main-content`

Well that's all for my post which is probably too long for most people sorry if I bored you, but I'm just trying to help.  Hope you figure out the layout you want.  This is only a few examples of the layouts possible with good old css.  If you don't get the layout you want from this or any other post feel free to send me a message by commenting below, and I'll be happy to answer it sometime. Hope this helped. If it didn't that's fine too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [css3 flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

http://jsfiddle.net/wL9aM/1/

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 700px;
}
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.main {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Are there any downsides to using `flexbox`? Such as compatibility?

Comment: @IAreKyleW00t just tested with firefox 27.0.1, it works well.

Comment: @IAreKyleW00t Flexbox is great and upcoming. It will support all new browsers (except opera mini), but it may not support all older browsers as it's a very new module in css3. Here is a link to compatibility with flexbox if you're interested. (http://caniuse.com/flexbox)  It definitley will be used in a couple years, because it offers some great new features for css like vertical centering.

Comment: @IAreKyleW00t Just found out about polyfills today. Just something to look out for when it becomes available. There is a polyfill for the css layout flex-box available for the 2009 spec of flexbox but not for the current spec.  More about polyfills here http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/ More about Old and New Flexbox specs http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/ More about flexbox http://html5please.com/#flexbox

Answer (score 1):

try using script..

```
var window_h = $(window).height();
var header_h = $("header").height(); //This is what you said you had 150px

$(".filler_div").height(window_h - header_h);
```

You can also put that inside a function() so that you can add it also when you resize the browser, the filler space also adjusts...

```
function setfillerDivHeight(){
   //the code above
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setFillerDivHeight(); //the initial setting of height
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    setFillerDivHeight(); //reapply setting of height when window resizes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="full-page-height-wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
</div>


html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  height: 150px;
}
.full-page-height-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

CODE: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N7zJg/9/

preview: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N7zJg/9/show/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you cannot acheive that in pure CSS.

So, there is two different solutions:

**1)** You can put the `150px div` in the `100% div`.

**2)** You can do it with jQuery:

If your top `div` is `<div id="A">` and the second one is `<div id="B">`, you'll have:

```
var b = $("#B");
var height = $("body").height() - b.position().top;
b.css({ height: height });
```

Feel free to adapt the code if you have some margins.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself finally. Doing it this way makes the design more responsive since (if i choose to add something to the bottom), it will automatically resize the div's height.

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.column {
    display: table-column;
}
#fullDiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two solution.
The one is that I have must set the div in the absolute position.
the div float over the screen.
another one is use table-row display.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just CSS, you cant achieve your task by giving 100% height to div. Because what basically CSS is doing is giving 100% height to your DIV plus giving 150 px to above header. Consider giving height of DIV less than 100% or some static value such as 600px or 700px.

Alternate is having a class of DIV with min-height 100% and inside it putting your header and body.